# keeping data structures in Julia managable

Tags: julia

What is the Julia way to make a large data structure without it becoming unruly?

for example

```
struct Struct1
    item1::Vector{Struct2}
end

struct Struct2
    item2::Vector{Struct3}
end

struct Struct3
    item3::Vector{Struct4}
end

struct Struct4
    item4::Vector{Struct5}
end

struct Struct5
    item5::Float64
end
```

to use `item5` I would need to initalize it all, and lets say I call it `LongChain = Struct1()`

Because there is no inheritance to use `item5` would require

```
LongChain.item1[i].item2[j].item3[k].item4[l].item5
```

That chain can become arbitrarily long... if there was inheritance, it would just be

```
LongChain.item5[i]
```

How does `Julia` avoid these long chains?

Comment: I wonder where you would really need such a data structure setup. It feels a bit like OOP paradigm? Maybe you could tell us what you want to do? In any case you could "inherit" fields in Julia (there are packages for that) or overwrite `getproperty` of `Struct1` for example.

Comment: Simulation->ForceFields->Property->Parameters

Comment: I messed that up...

Also, my other post which you have found, is my example. Although it isn't about simulation. I tried to make is more general so I used... buses. MainStruct is simulation, bus is forcefield, person(property) is a structure(parameters) that depends on the bus (FF)

Comment: I don't how inheritance would've helped as it is formulated. Maybe take a look at There are some good discussions here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/composition-and-inheritance-the-julian-way/11231/4 How would inheritance in another language help? It's a array of array of an array of things.

Comment: Inheritance would let item5 be absorbed into the first struct. In retrospect, this isnt' really a Julia question, it could apply equally well to C or any other language that isn't OOP. But since Julia's competition (OOP) has an answer, I believe the designers of Julia also have a smart answer. I just don't know it. I am waiting for them to grace me with their reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is that your design seems to be object-oriented, so an object-oriented language is designed to express this type of design. But there may be other solutions to your design.
Anyway, defining

```
getitem5(longchain::Struct1, i, j, k, l) = longchain.item1[i].item2[j].item3[k].item4[l].item5
```

should solve the issue. I don't see how this could ever be reduced to `LongChain.item5[i]` in Python given that in this case you're lacking the the indexing information into the other objects (j, k and l)? 
People asked about what you want to achieve (a prerequisite of SO questions) - just referring to "your other question" isn't actually helpin.

Comment: It especially doesn't help that I deleted the other question. I believe abstract types are my answer. What I really want is given a keyword, I want the program load a certain structure. If there were 2 options both of these structures would contain information on forcefields (i.e., parameter sets). They both have the same skeleton, but different numbers of parameters. I just want a general way to refer to a parameter at the bottom of the chain independent of the FF chosen. i.e. Simulation->Forcefield->BondType->Parameters. FF is a structure with Angles/Bonds/Dihedrals...

Comment: of which each of them are also structures with their respective (multiple) parameters(some scalar, some vectors). I tried to make the problem general by simply creating a chain of of generic structs for this example. I didn't think people cared about their names

Comment: I think what you are looking for is parametric types https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Parametric-Types-1

Comment: If you really want concrete inheritance you can get it with e.g. https://github.com/rjplevin/Classes.jl But it's more ideomatic to use composition with parametric types and abstract supertypes.

Comment: The pythonic programmer in me likes the Classes.jl route. I need to do more study, but thanks for these options, I think I can figure out what I need from them.